# Finding the thermal expectation value of a magnetic system from the partition function

Tags: quantum-spin, partition-function, mean-field-theory

Consider two coupled magnetic systems. The Hamiltonian of this system is:
$H_{eff} = \begin{bmatrix} H_{m_1} & U \\ U' & H_{m_2} \end{bmatrix}$. 
Each block is a $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian itself.

I'm not sure how to find the order parameter in $m_2$ system, which is the expectation value of the spin in that system. By creating the partition function we have:

$Z = Tr[\hat{\sigma} \cdot \exp(-\beta H_{eff})]$. which $\hat{\sigma}$ is the spin Pauli matrix.

The first problem is $H_{eff}$ is not diagonal and if I make it diagonal I mix the two orbitals.

The second problem is even if I mix the orbitals, the size of the Hamiltonian is $4\times 4$, but the size of $\hat{\sigma}$ is only $2\times 2$ so the dot product inside the bracket is impossible.

Is there any other way to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

The thermal expectation value of $m_2$ is $ \left\langle m_2 \right\rangle = \frac{Tr[(I_{2 \times 2} \otimes \hat{\sigma}) \cdot \exp( - \beta  H_{eff})]}{Tr[\exp( - \beta  H_{eff})]}$ in the basis you use, and it will fix the dimension issue. Usually we don't need to diagonalize the matrix, some function like MatrixExp in mathematica can tell you the matrix exponential.